# Proving $||x||-||y|| \leq ||x-y||$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, normed-spaces

I'm supposed to show how if $||\cdot||$ is a norm on vector space $X$ then $||x|| - ||y|| \leq ||x-y||$ for any two vectors $x,y \in X$

The properties I have for a norm are

1. $||x|| > 0$ if $x \neq \vec{0}$
2. $||\alpha x|| = |\alpha|||x||$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$
3. $||x+y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$ for any $x,y \in X$

Here's what I did.

$$
\begin{align*}
    ||x-y|| &=    ||x   +     (-y)|| \\
            &\leq ||x|| +     ||-y|| \\
            &=    ||x|| + |-1|||y|| \\
            &=    ||x|| + ||y||
\end{align*}
$$

Which is certainly true but not what I'm after.

Working the other direction I got the following.

$$
\begin{align*}
||x|| - ||y|| &= ||x||-||y|| \\
              &= ||x|| + (-||y||) 
\end{align*}
$$
But I believe that's a dead end...

Finally I tried multiplying by -1.

$$
\begin{align*}
  ||x-y|| &\leq ||x|| + ||y|| \\
 -||x-y|| &\geq -||x||-||y|| \\
  ||x-y|| &\geq -||x||-||y||
\end{align*}
$$
But then then I can't change the sign on the $-||x||$ because it may be a large enough increase to make the inequality not true...

I feel like this is supposed to be an easy question so I'm embarassed I can't figure it out yet. Help would be appreciaed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3507714/prove-for-any-vector-norm-cdot-that-left-x-y-right-leq?rq=1

Comment: The [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality) says that $\left|||x||-||y||\right|\le||x||-||y||$, from which your desired inequality $||x||-||y||\le||x||-||y||$ follows

Answer (score 4):

$||x||\le ||x-y|| + ||y||$ from property $3$.

Now subtract $||y||$ from both sides.

Answer (score 3):

$||x|| = ||x-y+y|| \le ||x-y||+||y||$

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

$y = (y - x) + x; \tag 1$

$\Vert y \Vert = \Vert (y - x) + x \Vert \le \Vert y - x \Vert + \Vert x \Vert; \tag 2$

this immediately yields

$\Vert y \Vert - \Vert x \Vert \le \Vert y - x \Vert; \tag 3$

this is in fact the desired result tho' I have reversed the roles of $x$ and $y$; (3) then also implies

$\Vert x \Vert - \Vert y \Vert \le \Vert x - y \Vert = \Vert y - x \Vert; \tag 4$

together (3) and (4) yield

$\vert \Vert x \Vert - \Vert y \Vert \vert \le \Vert x - y \Vert, \tag 5$

which is also known as the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: to show the equality in (4) we could do 
$||x-y|| = ||(-1)(-x+y)|| = |-1| ||y-x|| = ||y-x||$ right?

Comment: @financial_physician:  looks good to me!

Comment: so  $||x||-||y||$ and $||y||-||x||$ are both $\leq ||x-y||$ and $||y-x||$? That's surprising to me.

Comment: @financial_physician:  yes but recall $\Vert x - y \Vert = \Vert y - x \Vert$ and $\Vert x \Vert - \Vert y \Vert = -(\Vert y \Vert - \Vert x \Vert)$; so it all fits together.